# Slow performance when involving instance-wise gradient in distributed tensorflow

Tags: python, c, tensorflow

trying to use FtrlOptimizer to do a job. Since the original impl in tf is using batch gradient, I do a instance level by myself via numpy (plain python) as follows:

```
build tf graph()
read_data_res = sess.run()
delta_parameters = plain_python(read_data_res) # ftrl logic here
update_ps_op = sess.run(ops, feed_dict={delta_parameters})
```

It works as expected, but not efficient, I'm not sure if any way to improve this.

Additionally, how much work do I need if have to change the underlying C implementation? by far, don't have much idea about this.